# Give a function a unique ID

Tags: functions, widgets

I'm developing a theme that uses a Twitter Tweets custom widget (Not coded by me). There are several widget areas within the theme and if I try and include the Twitter widget in say the sidebar and the footer at the same time I get this error;

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare echo_tweets_js() (previously declared in..... on line.....
```

This is the section of offending code;

```
function echo_tweets_js() {
        global $pt_twitter_username, $pt_twitter_postcount;
        echo pt_twitter_js($pt_twitter_username, $pt_twitter_postcount);
    }

    add_action('wp_footer', 'echo_tweets_js', 9999);
```

Is there a way I can make it work if a user decides they want it in 2 places at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just... call the function again - you only need to include it once!

```
include './path/to/lib.php';

echo_tweet_js(); // a little tweeting here

...

echo_tweet_js(); // and a little tweeting over here!
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, I keep getting the same error... Functions are my downfall when it comes to Wordpress, especially widget functions so I could perhaps be doing something wrong

Comment: Somewhere in the execution of the script, that function is getting included more than once - find the original, & then remove all others.

Comment: To make @TheDeadMedic comment a little more clear: There's an `include/require` somewhere, that should be an `include_once/require_once`.

Comment: @kasier Not a huge fan of `*_once`, but regardless, would be a lot more elegant to simply remove the redundant includes.

Comment: That doesn't work either, in the functions.php file there's and include_once for another file which contains the twitter widget (Which doesn't have an include or require within it). I have uploaded the entire Twitter widget code here - http://jsfiddle.net/wXZzh/1/ if that helps anyway

Comment: That code is not the problem, it's wherever it's getting included *again*.